# Swift: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have an application with 3 targets dev, staging and prod.

The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function is called for the target prod, I don't understand why for the other target it doesn't called

Code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert]) { granted, _ in
    guard granted else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async  { application.registerForRemoteNotifications() }
}
```

However push notification is enabled for all target
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There may be a configuration problem that causes a failed APN registration.

1. Try printing out what you're getting in `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`, if you're using simulator it could be entering this method instead of `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.
2. Assure that your Provisioning Profile contains the aps-environment entry
3. Assure that you have a unique App Identifier (a string without any "*") set in your Provisioning Profile. You should also use this exact identifier as "Bundle identifier" in your Info.plist
4. Maybe you have declined the Push-Feature after the initial installation - in this case you will never see the in-app-push-alert again and have to enable Push in the settings app again.
5. Try another device.

Comment: I test on a real device, notifications are allowed, and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` not called

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen can you edit your question and include all steps you've tried? sometimes when I write down what I've done, I realize I've missed something. Also can you try deleting the app and restarting your phone? It's likely not the reason but it would help us know exactly what you've done in your own words. Having that said I think checking the provisioning profiles is key since your targets have different bundleIDs and likely AppIDs and so the capabilities of them could be different